# Copy n number of files from Azure Datalake to SFTP location using Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-lake, azure-cloud-services

**I have a scenario-**
I have some files in Azure Datalake. A job is pushing these file at an ADLS location.
This files needs to be uploaded at a SFTP location as a input data.
An application will consume this input file and will perform some operation and later save the processed data in an output directory as a output file at the same SFTP location.

With the help of Logic Apps I want to upload this output file at an ADLS location.

The application which consume this input file having some limitations- It can not consume more than 10000 records at a time. 
Viz if my source file having more than 10000 records then I have to split it into multiple files (depends on number of rows), and then I have to replicate these files to SFTP location.
This replication has to be perform in such a way than after completion of one job only then another file should be copied at the SFTP location.

To upload the files I want to use to Azure Logic Apps.

As per my understanding till now Azure Logic Apps does not provide any Trigger to test '**a file added or modified**' the ADLS location but Logic Apps having similar type of feature for the blob storage so I decided to use blob container.
Once my raw file are uploaded to the in ADLS location I will upload a file to blob location, 
as my Logic Apps would keep polling this specific directory so whenever any new file arrives immediately it will trigger the file copy job via the Logic Apps.

**Now the problem-**
My ADLS directory may have one or more file(s).
How do I create a copy activity in Logic Apps to replicate these file(s) to the SFTP location.
How do I identify that how many **csv** type file are available in ADLS directory so that my logic apps decides number of iteration to copy the file.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use List File Action on ADLS..

Output of this action is documented here  -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatalake/#folderresponse

This is basically an array of filestatus class objects.. you can loop through this array and extract information from status objects and use it to copy data to where ever you want..

FileStatus has info -

TABLE 14
Name    Path    Type    Description
File name   pathSuffix  string
File or folder name.

Type    type    string
Type of item (directory or file).

Block Size  blockSize   integer 
Block size of folder or file.

Access Time accessTime  integer 
Unix (Epoch) time when the item last accessed.

Modification Time   modificationTime    integer 
Unix (Epoch) time when the item last modified.

Sample LA would look like -

[image]